# Formula/algorithm to merge and sort arrays into one

Tags: php

I have four arrays that I need to merge/sort pragmatically.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e041YuQCUVu4_hgu1uCGaKILrL5a3WqReEeKtCeGLOs/edit?usp=sharing

The link above shows the contents of the arrays.

The left-most array is the desired array. The four other arrays are the data that I have to merge/sort in order to arrive at the desired array on the left.

I am very much capable of writing the code in PHP but I can't come up with the theory as to how to go about dealing with the data to arrive at the desired array.

Can anyone help me come up with a solution? This is a specific example but this same comparison will happen on around 400,000 other arrays like this. I just need the theory to get from the 4 arrays to 1 array.

Comment: Should be moved to https://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @wallyk: It's not off-topic here.

Comment: Please do not **[cross-post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/283664/22815)**. Recommended reading: **[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/255171)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_merge](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to put the arrays together, then use [array_unique](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to get rid of duplicate values.

Comment: You can also use [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) to sort it afterwards. Or any of [these](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: As I said in the question, I have a desired array that I am trying to merge the 4 arrays into. `array_merge` and `array_unique` are far too generic. I have to merge in a specific order.

Comment: @user3605739 You define the order with array_merge. Put the arrays in the order you want them merged. The first array is the base. The second array is merged into the first. The third is merged into that result, and so on. I don't know what you mean by them being "too generic", especially array_unique since all that does is remove repeated values. Then, as Vic said you can use asort to sort them or [usort](https://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) if you don't want it to be more specific to your needs.

Comment: @Newspire My apologies, I misunderstood exactly what `array_merge` did. Using this with `usort` looks like it could work. Thanks for your answer.